# Is there any pattern to the z80's opcode layout?

Tags: opcode, z80

I'm trying to write an emulator for the z80, and am wondering if there is any specific opcode layout (i.e. do all the `ld` instructions have a specific bit set). I've looked [here](http://z80-heaven.wikidot.com/opcode-reference-chart) but if there's an indication of a pattern, I haven't found it yet.

Is there? If there is, please give me a few examples.

Comment: The linked documentation *is* the pattern. What exactly are you looking for and why?

Comment: I was hoping for some sort of way to optimize. For example, if all X instructions have Y register number added to Z value, and if Y is the same for each instruction, I could easily implement the emulator and decrease code size. As it is, I'll have to implement each instruction by hand.

Comment: I'm not at a place to give a full fledged answer, but yes, there are many patterns. For example, for `ld [reg8],[reg8]`, the opcode is %01xxxyyy where xxx corresponds to the first operand and yyy corresponds to the second. b=000, c=001, ..., l=101, (hl)=110, and a=111. The exception is `halt` which is 76 and would correspond to `ld (hl),(hl)`. This might be more useful for you: http://tutorials.eeems.ca/ASMin28Days/ref/z80is.html

Comment: That page links to [this](http://www.z80.info/decoding.htm).

Comment: Thank you! Those links are useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, there's a pattern. This page:

http://www.z80.info/decoding.htm

explains the encoding of various Z80 instructions, both documented and undocumented ones.

The `ld c, d` instruction, for example, is encoded as `LD r[y], r[z]` with the `x` field (the two most significant bits) of the op-code set to 1 and three-bit fields `y` and `z` (bits 3-5 and 0-2 respectively) set to 1 and 2.

To give you an example of how that can be implemented in an emulator, here's a link to my implementation of the decoder:
[z80.h](https://github.com/kosarev/z80/blob/8609eca52bba950421e3aec778c3f6f572be1e33/z80.h#L368).